# How do I connect to my database using a web app and Jetty Runner?

Tags: postgresql, grails, jdbc, jetty, jndi

I have a postgresql database and I need to connect it to my web app(created in Grails) using Jetty Runner. What's the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify the database (JDBC) settings for a grails app in `grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy`. For a postgres database you'll want something like:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    username = "user1258361"
    password = "lmgtfy"
    url = "jdbc:postgresql:user1258361"

    // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
    // if you don't know what this does, find out now!!!
    dbCreate = "update" 
}
```

You'll need to substitute your real database URL, username, password for the dummy values I've provided above